# rugarch (ugarchroll) - out-of-sample forecasts' calendar dates are different from initial out-of-sample period

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I'm trying to generate daily rolling out-of-sample forecasts with an ARCH(1) model by using the `ugarchroll` function in the `rugarch` package in R. However, these out-of-sample forecasts have different calendar dates compared to the original out-of-sample return series, and thus do not match.

To clarify, my in-sample period starts from *2000-01-05* to *2004-08-06* (1,000 observations), while the out-of-sample period starts from *2004-08-09* to *2018-03-27* (3,078 observations).

My sample data looks like this:

```
> show(Data_v016_inclEM)
# A tibble: 4,078 x 68
   date1          t sp_op sp_cp sp_high sp_low mxx_op mxx_cp mxx_high mxx_low hsi_op hsi_cp hsi_high hsi_low ks_op
   <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>    <dbl>   <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2000-01-05     1 1396. 1402.   1413.  1378.  6675.  6764     6781.   6524. 16609. 15847.   16609.  15688. 1007.
 2 2000-01-06     2 1399. 1403.   1412.  1392.  6764.  6752.    6822.   6743. 15942. 15153.   15971.  14764. 1014.
 3 2000-01-07     3 1403. 1441.   1441.  1401.  6769.  7047.    7054.   6769. 15329. 15406.   15514.  15109.  949.
 4 2000-01-10     4 1441. 1457.   1464.  1441.  7048.  7334.    7337.   7048. 15631  15848.   16065.  15631   980.
 5 2000-01-11     5 1457. 1438.   1459.  1434.  7332.  7143.    7363.   7078. 15981. 15862.   16196.  15736.  992.
 6 2000-01-12     6 1439. 1432.   1443.  1427.  7143.  7174.    7174.   7091. 15692. 15714.   15744.  15546.  958.
 7 2000-01-13     7 1432. 1450.   1454.  1432.  7174.  7275.    7426.   7174. 15763. 15634.   15861.  15459.  955.
 8 2000-01-14     8 1450. 1464.   1473   1450.  7279.  7381.    7394.   7279. 15742. 15542.   15863.  15322.  959.
 9 2000-01-18     9 1465. 1455.   1465.  1451.  7447.  7304.    7447.   7302. 15576. 15789.   15801.  15508.  992.
10 2000-01-19    10 1452. 1456.   1461.  1449.  7303.  7171.    7311.   7171. 15719. 15275.   15719.  15192.  969.
# ... with 4,068 more rows, and 53 more variables
```

I used the following codes to perform daily rolling ARCH(1) forecasts:

```
ARCH_1 <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,0)),mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)))
Fit_ARCH_1 <- ugarchfit(spec = ARCH_1, data = Data_v016_inclEM$ret_sp_index, out.sample = 3078, solver = "hybrid")
Var_ARCH_1 <- Fit_ARCH_1@fit$var

# Out-of-sample rolling forecasts #    
cluster <- makePSOCKcluster(10)
          CVAR_ARCH1_h1 <- ugarchroll(ARCH_1, Data_v016_inclEM$ret_sp_index, n.ahead = 1, forecast.length = 3078, n.start = 1000, refit.every = 1, refit.window = "moving", window.size = 1000, solver = "hybrid", solver.control = list(tol = 1e-6, trace = 1), keep.coef = TRUE, fit.control = list(scale = 1))
          CVAR_ARCH1_h1 <- resume(CVAR_ARCH1_h1, solver = "gosolnp")
          show(CVAR_ARCH1_h1)
          stopCluster(cluster)
          View(CVAR_ARCH1_h1@forecast$density)
          report(CVAR_ARCH1_h1)
          report(CVAR_ARCH1_h1, type = "fpm")
```

The daily rolling ARCH(1) forecasts somehow starts from a different calendar date compared to the abovementioned out-of-sample period. As you can see from the results below, it creates a date entry starting from *1972-09-28* to *1981-03-02*.

```
> show(CVAR_ARCH1_h1)

*-------------------------------------*
*              GARCH Roll             *
*-------------------------------------*
No.Refits       : 3078
Refit Horizon   : 1
No.Forecasts    : 3078
GARCH Model     : sGARCH(1,0)
Distribution    : norm 

Forecast Density:
                         Mu  Sigma Skew Shape Shape(GIG) Realized
1972-09-28 01:00:00 -0.0274 0.0113    0     0          0   0.0014
1972-09-29 01:00:00 -0.0261 0.0238    0     0          0   0.0125
1972-09-30 01:00:00 -0.0256 0.0341    0     0          0  -0.0031
1972-10-01 01:00:00 -0.0249 0.0218    0     0          0  -0.0115
1972-10-02 01:00:00 -0.0004 0.0138    0     0          0   0.0015
1972-10-03 01:00:00 -0.0313 0.0328    0     0          0   0.0137

..........................
                       Mu  Sigma Skew Shape Shape(GIG) Realized
1981-02-25 01:00:00 8e-04 0.0062    0     0          0  -0.0124
1981-02-26 01:00:00 8e-04 0.0107    0     0          0  -0.0018
1981-02-27 01:00:00 5e-04 0.0064    0     0          0  -0.0255
1981-02-28 01:00:00 4e-04 0.0180    0     0          0  -0.0212
1981-03-01 01:00:00 7e-04 0.0158    0     0          0   0.0269
1981-03-02 01:00:00 8e-04 0.0184    0     0          0  -0.0175

Elapsed: 26.66044 mins
```

So, how is it possible that these out-of-sample forecasts' calendar dates are not matching with calendar dates from the abovementioned out-of-sample period? What steps am I possibly missing to conduct this rolling forecasts properly? And how can I fix this minor problem?

Appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert your data from `tibble` to an `xts` object. You can use the `tk_xts` function from the [timetk](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/timetk/versions/2.8.1/topics/tk_xts) library. For instance,

```
library(timetk)
Data_v016_inclEM <- tk_xts(Data_v016_inclEM,  date_col = Data_v016_inclEM$date1)
```

[See this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69980832/436193)