# Select dates in 'rugarch' forecast R

Tags: r, date, datetime, lubridate

I have daily stock market data for a specific year, as stock market is open only in business days I have a dataset for a given year (say 2021) but I only have 245 data points that correspond to the days that the stock market was open.

Since I want to forecast the first say 4 days of 2022 and estimation of models require data points that are continuous, I resolved to use `decimal_date()` (from `lubridate`) to get the first date of my decimal 2021 time index, and assume that data points are equidistant in an artificial manner. Then my `ts`object looks like this starting from the first business day of 2021:

```
library(lubridate)
x<-ts(rnorm(245),start=decimal_date(ymd("2021-01-04")),frequency = 245)
```

Which is:

```
>x
Time Series:
Start = 2021.00821917808 
End = 2022.00413754543 
Frequency = 245
```

Then I use `rugarch` package to estimate a GARCH model for this data:

```
library(rugarch)
garch_setup <- ugarchspec(
  mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(1,1), include.mean=TRUE), #ARIMA
  variance.model=list(garchOrder=c(0,1)), #GARCH
  distribution.model = "norm")

garch_fit <- ugarchfit(spec = garch_setup, data = x, solver ='hybrid')
```

Then when I want to forecast turns out that the dates assigned (index) to the data points in the model correspond to Epoch time and not my previously assigned dates in `ts` and `decimal_date()` functions:

```
forecast_garch <- ugarchforecast(garch_fit, n.ahead=4)
```

Checking forecast indexes:

```
>forecast_garch@model$modeldata$index
  [1] "1970-01-01 19:00:00 -05" "1970-01-02 19:00:00 -05" "1970-01-03 19:00:00 -05"
  [4] "1970-01-04 19:00:00 -05" "1970-01-05 19:00:00 -05" "1970-01-06 19:00:00 -05"
  [7] "1970-01-07 19:00:00 -05" "1970-01-08 19:00:00 -05" "1970-01-09 19:00:00 -05"
...
```

What should I do in order to make `rugarch` functions take my `ts`'s object date indexes in estimating and forecasting?

Thanks!

PD: Ignore the fact that to this date 2021 is still ongoing.

Answer (score 1):

From the Changelog:

2013-01-30  Alexios Ghalanos alexios@4dscape.com

- DESCRIPTION (Version): New version is 1.01-3.

[...]

- xts is now the only supported data "format" accepted by the package. Numeric, data.frame and matrix data which does not have a proper time based index is coerced into one by assuming the numerical index of the supplied data represents number of days since 1970-01-01 (the warning is turned off at present).

[...]